# Connect to SQLite database using qt

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I am having trouble connecting to my sqlite database using my qt application.
I have a helper class DBManager that is supposed to have functions to open and close the database, as I would like to reuse the code in multiple places.
Here is the dbmanager.cpp

```
DBManager::DBManager()
{

}
void DBManager::connOpen()
{

    path = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/GameSuitedb.db";
    mydb=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    mydb.setDatabaseName(path);

void DBManager::connClose() /*Closes connection and commits changes to database*/
{
    mydb.close();
    mydb.removeDatabase(QSqlDatabase::defaultConnection);
}
```

Note my database is named GameSuitedb and is located next to the executable
And here is where I am trying to access my database:

```
void CreateUser::on_pushButton_submit_clicked()
{
    dbmanager.connOpen();
    QString username = ui->lineEdit_username->text();
    QString password = ui->lineEdit_password->text(); //Gets password text
    QSqlQuery qry(dbmanager.mydb);
    qry.prepare("INSERT INTO users (username,password) VALUES ('"+username+"', '"+password+"')");

    if(qry.exec()){
    }
    else{
        ui->statusbar->showMessage(qry.lastError().text());
    }
        dbmanager.connClose();
}
```

The error the above code gives me when launched is QSqlQuery::prepare: database not open.

Comment: Have you verified in your debugger than the `path` variable is what you think it is? Also, read up on how to use prepared queries -- your current code contains an obvious opportunity for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: The sqlite support in qt will at least try to create a new db if the database file does not exist in the folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error code tells you that the database is not open because your `DBManager::connOpen()` function seems to be doing everything except actually opening the database, contrary to how it's named.

You need to call [`QSqlDatabase::open()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#open%20QSqlDatabase::open()) at the end of `DBManager::connOpen()` function so that the database gets opened and will be made ready for use.

```
void DBManager::connOpen()
{
    path = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/GameSuitedb.db";
    mydb=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    mydb.setDatabaseName(path);
    if(!mydb.open())
    {
        //use lastError() here to figure out what went wrong.  
    }
}
```